# How do I run specific golang test using go test -run

Tags: go

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to run this one ConnectionPoolTest.TestNew and what ever I try, I get back 'no test to run'

```
:go test  --check.list *.go |grep Connectio
ConnectionPoolTest.TestNew
:go test  --run ConnectionPoolTest *.go
ok      command-line-arguments  0.005s [no tests to run]
:go test  --run ConnectionPoolTest.TestNew *.go
ok      command-line-arguments  0.005s [no tests to run]
```

Comment: `go test` requires packages, not go files, and to filter what tests you want to run, use `-run X`, where `X` is a regexp that will be matched against test names. Run `go help test` for more details; and [Go tool: Test packages](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages); and [Go tool: Description of testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags).

Comment: I don't understand. Is there a simple way to run that one test  by itself. My regex should match the test output by -check.list

Comment: To run that test alone, go to its folder, and type: `go test -run TestNew`. If you have other tests whose name contas the `TestNew` substring, then run `go test -run ^TestNew$`.

Comment: That is how I thought it would work but it's not
    go test --run ^TestNew$
    testing: warning: no tests to run
    PASS
   
    go test -check.vv --run TestNew
    testing: warning: no tests to run
    PASS

Comment: Just one dash: `-run`, and make sure you're in the package's folder, else you have to pass the package name too.

Comment: Then there is no test called `TestNew` in your current package. What is `--check.list`? You can list all tests with `go test -list .`

Comment: go test -list . only outputs Test. go test -run Test runs all tests

Comment: @AC. then you only have a test called `Test`, and that is running all the others. Again, what is `--check.list` from? Presumably you're using some sort of test suite package, and that has flags to filter what tests to run.

Comment: Sorry, this is someone else's code that got thrown at me. I see they imported . "gopkg.in/check.v1"; I need to look into whether this is somehow causing me issues

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to run a specific test, you may run as bellow

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    assert.True(t, true)
}

func TestB(t *testing.T) {
    assert.True(t, false)
}
```

Run Test:

```
$ go test -run B
--- FAIL: TestB (0.00s)
        Error Trace:    a_test.go:13
        Error:          Should be true
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    test    0.004s
$ go test -run A
PASS
ok      test    0.003s
shahriar@Kite ~/g/s/test>
```

`-run` flag

```
-run regexp
        Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression.
        For tests the regular expression is split into smaller ones by
        top-level '/', where each must match the corresponding part of a
        test's identifier.
```

Comment: The code base is using "gopkg.in/check.v1" and to run a specific test one needs to use -check.f REGEX where REGEX is the regex for the name of the suite.test

Comment: You can answer your own question, if you have more appropriate answer. @AC. Then it will help everyone